# Should I use an object class or broadcast variable

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an coordinates RDD[(Int,Int)] and I want to create a new RDD[(Int,(Int,Int))] what is the best practice?

```
object GlobalVariables{

  private var pointId : Int = 0

  def newPointId(): Long ={
    pointId += 1
    pointId
  }

}

points = coordinates.map(x=> (GlobalVariables.newPointID,x._1, x._2))
```

1. Is this code executed on workers or should I use a combination of broadcast Variables and accumulators?
2. If the code is executed on workers how can I be sure that I will not have any concurrency error?

Answer (score 0):

You can try another solution without the need to have mutable counter, The transformation `zipWithIndex` provides a stable indexing, numbering each element in its original order.
example :

```
val myRdd = RDD(1,2,3)
val zippedWithIndex = myRdd.zipWithIndex //  ((1,0),(2,1),(3,2))
```

After this first transormation you can flip the index and the value

```
val result = zippedWithIndex.map{case (index,value) => (value,index)}  // ((0,1),(1,2),(2,3))
```